# Trouble Returning to App from External App

Tags: ios, url

I'm building an app where the user can open the IMDB app to a particular actor or visit that page via Safari if they don't have the IMDB app installed.

```
NSString *imdbWebLink = @"http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1090683/";
NSString *imdbAppLink = @"imdb:///name/nm1090683";

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imdbAppLink]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imdbAppLink];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imdbWebLink];
}
```

The above code works fine but I would like the IMDB App back button to return the user to my app. So I set up a URL type (named bundle identifier) and a custom URL scheme (named bundle identifier with the periods removed) in info.plist for the app. I then modified imdbAppLink following x-callback-url protocol:

```
imdbAppLink = @"imdb://x-callback-url/name/nm1090683/?x-success=custom_url_scheme&x-source=AppName";
```

The IMDB app opens correctly to the requested page but the Back button takes the user to the IMDB home screen and not to my app.

I've been researching this for hours here on Stack and on Google to no avail, yet lots of interesting dead ends. As Princess Leia once said, "Help me, Obi-Wan Kenobi; you're my only hope."

If you visit the imdb link above, you will see some of my non-iPhone work, but suffice is to say that I would prefer for the user to return directly to the app rather than indirectly with a bunch of Home button clicks.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X-callback-url has to be implemented in the app that you're opening, otherwise it will not work.

Do you have any reason to believe that IMDB supports it? I don't see IMDB listed at http://x-callback-url.com/apps/.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. That makes sense. I was hoping that since Google was there with Chrome and Maps that IMDB would be also and that the list you posted was not up to date. The thing is I also want to do do the same thing with Facebook native app in my app and Facebook is not listed ether.

Comment: I maintain a [library for x-callback-url apps](https://onetapless.com/library). It is mentioned at the bottom of the official list linked by Andrew. I update it weekly and I'm always inquiring developers for documentation and support.

Comment: Thank you Phillip. I will definitely check it out. Perhaps Facebook and IMDB (the two apps I'm interested in communicating with) will support x-callback-url in the future and I can push a new version.